# What are the common approaches to estimate GGX roughness from reflectance, normals, albedo, and appearance?

Tags: graphics, computer-vision

I have a minimal light stage setup to scan heads:

- I have cross polarized cameras and parallel polarized cameras.
- I have parallel polarized LEDs
- I capture k-frames and tracking frames

I am able to:

- calculate normals and color albedos from Photometric Stereo (Woodham)
- calculate a mesh via Photogrammetry
- project normals, albedo and appearance on the mesh
- create a reflectance map (via parallel - cross)

Does anybody have a tip?

I tried a statistical approach which gives unsatisfactory results.
Some rough areas were smooth while some smooth areas were rough.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's a better fit on https://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/. it's not a programming question but a theory question.